# Tycho integration test are not run (but Unit tests are..)

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, integration-testing, tycho

I have a multi module project with a plugin and fragment to test this plugin.
The build is done through maven/tycho. Maven v.3.8.4 and Tycho v2.6.0.

In the fragment I have 3 Unit and 1 Integration test, in the test folder:

```
test
   ├── CoreTestConstants.java
   ├── CoreUtils2Test.java
   ├── CoreUtils3Test.java
   ├── CoreUtilsIT.java
   └── CoreUtilsTest.java
```

This is the pom of the fragment plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <artifactId>com.tycho.rcp.core.test</artifactId>
     <version>0.2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

     <parent>
          <groupId>com.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>com.tycho.mps</artifactId>
          <version>0.3.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <relativePath>..</relativePath>
     </parent>

     <build>
          <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
          <plugins>
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                         <execution>
                              <id>it-test</id>
                              <phase>integration-test</phase>
                              <goals>
                                   <goal>integration-test</goal>
                              </goals>
                         </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                         <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>
                         <testClassesDirectory>target/classes</testClassesDirectory>

                         <!-- workspace directory -->
                         <osgiDataDirectory>${mas.test.workspace}</osgiDataDirectory>

                         <!-- system properties -->
                         <systemProperties>
                              <mas.test.archive_location>${mas.test.archive_location}</mas.test.archive_location>
                         </systemProperties>

                         <!-- add slf4j implementation dependency from Orbit -->
                         <dependencies>
                              <dependency>
                                   <groupId>org.eclipse.orbit.bundles</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>ch.qos.logback.slf4j</artifactId>
                                   <version>1.1.2</version>
                                   <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                              </dependency>
                         </dependencies>
                    </configuration>
               </plugin>
          </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

The tycho-surefire-plugin is enabled in pluginManagement of the parent project:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
   <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${tycho.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

The 3 Unit test are executed correctly, but the IT test is never run!
This is the relevant part of the output, when I run `mvn clean verify` inside the fragment project:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:test (default-test) @ com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test ---
[INFO] Executing Test Runtime with timeout 0, logs (if any) will be placed at: /home/gionata/runtime-EclipseApplication/.metadata/.log
[INFO] Command line:
    [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.fc31.x86_64/bin/java, -Dosgi.noShutdown=false, -Dosgi.os=linux, -Dosgi.ws=gtk, -Dosgi.arch=x86_64, -Dosgi.clean=true, -Dmas.test.archive_location=/home/gionata/ARCHIVIO.BLK, -jar, /home/gionata/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/1.5.100.v20180827-1352/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar, -data, /home/gionata/runtime-EclipseApplication, -install, /home/gionata/Workspace_Eclipse_Maven/MAS/MPS/com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test/target/work, -configuration, /home/gionata/Workspace_Eclipse_Maven/MAS/MPS/com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test/target/work/configuration, -application, org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest, -testproperties, /home/gionata/Workspace_Eclipse_Maven/MAS/MPS/com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test/target/surefire.properties]
Running com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils2Test
Logger launcher start...4
2022-02-05 18:36:11,221 DEBUG [main]: CHECKSUM 2 = 340351cde832c00505c88f3fe1a962d4
2022-02-05 18:36:11,442 DEBUG [main]: Workspace = /home/gionata/runtime-EclipseApplication
2022-02-05 18:36:11,442 DEBUG [main]: Archive location = /home/gionata/ARCHIVIO.BLK
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.569 s - in com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils2Test
testCoreUtils2(com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils2Test)  Time elapsed: 0.226 s
Running com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtilsTest

#################################################################################
REPORT
CHECKSUM = 340351cde832c00505c88f3fe1a962d4

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtilsTest
testCoreUtils(com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s
Running com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils3Test
Logger launcher start...4
2022-02-05 18:36:11,537 DEBUG [main]: CHECKSUM 3 = 340351cde832c00505c88f3fe1a962d4
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.024 s - in com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils3Test
testCoreUtils3(com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test.CoreUtils3Test)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s

Results:

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] All tests passed!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:integration-test (it-test) @ com.marchesini.mas.rcp.core.test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The execution **it-test** simply doesn't run anything! I have been wasting hours on this....

Thankyou for any help.

Comment: Missing `<useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>` or is it a headless RCP application? Read https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Comment: Its a headless app.. I tried with `<useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>` but nothing chages..

Comment: Plain JUnit tests and Plug-in tests should be separated. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or start with [this working Tycho example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) and adapt it to your needs ([which also includes RCP integration tests](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/tree/master/tests/com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests)).

Comment: OK, I tried to provide a minimal example here: https://github.com/gion86/tycho.test
is really the minimal code, with one unit test running and the IT not running. 
To run the full build go to folder com.tycho.test.rcp.releng and run `mvn clean verify`.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your example on GitHub shows a plugin and a corresponding test fragment only. For integration tests you need a product to be built first to be able to run the integration tests inside an application of the product. See [the integration tests in the Tycho exmple](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/tree/master/tests/com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests) which will be [run after the product has been built](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L133-L134).

Comment: OK, I've added a feature, product and even a test plugin only for integration test.  It seems that the integration-test goal is run only in product plugin `--- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:integration-test (default-integration-test) @ com.tycho.test.rcp.product ---`.  I moved the test after the product in the reactor include order (if that matters). But only the `tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:test` goal is executed in the eclipse-test-plugins. The tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:integration-test is run only in the eclipse-plugins.

Comment: And regarding the tycho example: the com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests module is commented out. If you uncomment it, there is a bug in the parent reference in the com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests pom itself. Once fixed the bug the command `./mvnw clean verify` will run the test goal and not the integration-test: `--- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.3.0:test (default-test) @ com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests ---`. Maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: Re-enabling the integrations tests works for me in the Tycho example: https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/pull/18 For running Maven with Java 17 I also had to update Tycho from 2.3 to the current version 2.6: https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/pull/19

Comment: I use Java11, with the maven wrapper from the tycho-example project, and I tried with tycho 2.3 and 2.6. The same thing happens: the goal that run the integrations test, like com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests.swtbot.TestMenus is `--- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:test (default-test) @ com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests ---` and not `--- tycho-surefire-plugin:2.6.0:integration-test (default-integration-test) @ com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests ---`
Is it ok? The tests run, even with UI, so it could be acceptable...

Comment: Or maybe it should be `tycho-failsafe-plugin` to run the IT test isn't it?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. When I run the [parent POM `clean verify` here in my `reenable_integration_tests` branch](https://github.com/howlger/tycho-example/tree/reenable_integration_tests), the file `tests/com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests.swtbot.TestMenus.xml` (containing the test results) will be created which proves that the integration tests will be executed (in the Tycho example, there is a single UI test via SWTBot in `com.vogella.tycho.rcp.it.tests`).

Comment: In your example, use for JUnit `Import-Package` instead of `Require-Bundle`: replace [this](https://github.com/gion86/TychoITTestExample/blob/9d5b10da9ebe4fbdc35bac1b3d0f01d89aa0739d/com.tycho.test.rcp.product.tests/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L9) with [that](https://github.com/howlger/tycho-example/blob/aab450fef79e4c7c365c04bee1edc31c384ef10a/tests/com.vogella.tycho.plugin1.tests/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L11-L12). See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/JUnit5

Comment: I mean that the IT test should be run in the integration-test goal of the tycho-surefire-plugin. Instead, from what I see in the example, they are run in the test goal. Which is not the same: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html

I will try with Import-Package, but I'm using Junit 4.12 and not 5...

Comment: I see, but I don't know how to run the test(s) in the integration-test goal (or phase?) and what's the benefit of doing so.

Comment: @lorenzo-bettini Thanks for the explanation and for reporting it. Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Thankyou very much @lorenzo-bettini for the clarification. I've cleaned up a bit my example. I've left only the default configuration. It's ready for test with Tycho 2.7, where I think the bug will be fixed!

Comment: @howlger I've just turned my comment to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't add any specific configuration if you follow the default conventions. Moreover, parameters like `<testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>` are not read by the tycho surefire plugin. Moreover, there's no need to create products or features for what you need. The reason why it's not working it's because of a bug:
https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/issues/643

On a side note, I've updated the RELEASE notes
https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/pull/641
trying to document better the rationale behind the new goal (but, again, it does not work due to a bug)